# Google App Engine json post request body

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, post

I can't read body from POST request on Google app engine application whenever I send string which contains colon ":"

This is my request handler class:

```
class MessageSync(webapp.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    print self.request.body
```

Ad this is my testing script:

```
import httplib2

json_works = '{"works"}'
json_doesnt_work = '{"sux": "test"}'
h = httplib2.Http()

resp, content = h.request('http://localhost:8080/msg', 
        'POST', 
        json_works ,
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

print content
```

If I use variable json_works request body gets printed, but if I use json_doest_work I won't get any response to console. Except if I print whole request object I get this:

```
POST /msg
Content-Length: 134
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Python-httplib2/$Rev$

{"sux": "test"}
```

Why the hack I can't get just body?
Thanks!

Comment: Does your actual code omit the closing single-quote in the definition of `json_doesnt_work` or is that just an artifact of coying the code into the question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the case of `json_doesnt_work`, the `print` function is setting the `self.request.body` as a `Response header` because it's in a form of a `{key:value}` parameter.

```
{'status': '200', 'content-length': '0',
 'expires': 'Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT',
 'server': 'Development/1.0',
 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
 'date': 'Tue, 22 Feb 2011 21:54:15 GMT',
 '{"sux"': '"test"}', <=== HERE!
 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
}
```

You should modify your handler like this:

```
class MessageSync(webapp.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    print ''
    print self.request.body
```

or even better

```
class MessageSync(webapp.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "text/plain"
    self.response.out.write(self.request.body)
```

Comment: You should never use `print` in a request handler at all.  +1 for the "even better" suggestion.

Comment: I'd upvote this answer if it didn't first suggest the awful, broken solution of using print anyway.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I later actually did try to use response.out.write and it worked, but I didn't know why print won't work.

Comment: Those print statements are _outside_ a WSGI app - they're in CGI examples. You should never, ever use print inside a WSGI app, because the app itself is responsible for outputting the results (including headers).